# Proof that $ x \leq y$ and $y \leq x \Rightarrow x =$ $y$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I need to prove that if $ x \leq y$ and $y \leq x \Rightarrow x =$ $y$.

I tried to prove this by contradiction.

**Proof**
Suppose that $ x \leq y$ and $y \leq x \Rightarrow x \neq y$. If $x \neq y$, we know out of the properties of inequalities that $x<y$ or $y<x$, which is the contradiction. Therefore $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x \Rightarrow x =$ $y$.

Is this proof correct and what other ways are there to prove this?

Comment: What definition are you using? With a natural definition, it's trivial that if $x$ is either less than or equal to $y$ but isn't less than $y$ then…. Alternatively, $\leq$ is sometimes defined axiomatically to be antisymmetric so it's true by definition.

Comment: It may be better to write your proof in the light of $x-y$ being simultaneously greater than or less than $0$ since that is more tangible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$y\ge x$ and $x \ge y$ gives us $y\ge x \ge y$ because $y=y$, $\;$ $y=x$ must also hold

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge y$ : Let$$x = y+a  \quad\quad\quad \text{(1.)}$$
For $y\ge x$ : Let$$y = x+b  \quad\quad\quad \text{(2.)}$$

Substituting $(1.)$ in $(2.)$

$$y = y+a+b$$ yielding $a=-b$. Putting this in $(1.) $ and $(2.)$
$$x=y-b$$

And 
$$y=x+b$$

Adding this results in $$2x=2y \implies \boxed{\color{blue}{x=y}}$$

Comment: Do $a,b$ have to be non-negative?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are adding? If you add the last 2 equations involving b you get $x+y=y+x$?

Comment: This doesn't work. Adding the two equations either gives $x+y=x+y$ as @PM. said or $2x+2b=2y$ which is just equation $(2.)$ multiplied by $2$. There's no conclusion here unless you require $a,b\ge0$, and then use $a=-b$ to conclude that $a,b=0$

Comment: They implicitly must be non-negative